# Safely render HTML template with inline CSS from trusted domain (it forces the use of "style-src: unsafe-inline" in CSP)

Tags: xss, content-security-policy

I am working with a form that a user can fill out to send an e-mail. As part of the form, there is a preview button that shows the user a preview of how the mail will look in a new tab in the browser. The e-mail template itself is defined in a 3rd party service. The site the form is on is protected with a log-in.

When the user clicks the preview button, this happens:

1. The template is fetched from the 3rd party service on the web server.
2. Information from the form is HTML encoded and added to the template on the web server.
3. The template is returned as HTML to the user's browser, where it is displayed in a new tab. The new tab contains *only* the e-mail template, since the template has it's own complete markup.

The challenge with this is that the template comes with inline styling, which violates the CSP, but which we need to show a correct preview of the template. To mitigate the risks of specifying `style-src 'unsafe-inline';` in the CSP header, I've added that rule *only* to the URL serving the template. This is the complete CSP header for the template preview page:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' https://some-domain-we-load-images.from;
```

Since it [might be possible to execute JavaScript from CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476276/using-javascript-in-css#answer-482088), [exfiltrate data with CSS](https://scarybeastsecurity.blogspot.com/2009/12/generic-cross-browser-cross-domain.html), as well as perform other exploits, I still feel uneasy about this. Maybe an option could be to generate nonces for the CSS, but I am not sure if that works for inline CSS attributes. I've done some testing, and it seems that `default-src` blocks a lot of attack vectors, but my knowledge in this area is incomplete. Also, according to [Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp?utm_source=devtools#policy_applies_to_a_wide_variety_of_resources), there's a few CSP resource directives that doesn't use `default-src` as a fallback, and it's these:

- base-uri
- form-action
- frame-ancestors
- plugin-types
- report-uri
- sandbox

I'm unsure if not specifying these will cause any real implications, give that the e-email template preview page is very limited in what it does.

The way I see it, an attacker could inject CSS in one of the following ways:

- From the form fields. They are all HTML encoded before added to the HTML.
- In the 3rd party service, but they would need the login credentials, or exploit some vulnerability with the service.

Is there any way to safely render inline styling in HTML from a trusted 3rd party domain? I am starting to lean towards not rendering the template as a preview, but instead sending an actual e-mail to the user so they can preview it that way.

Since the preview page contains only the previewed template, there isn't sensitive information on the page (unless the user enters some in the form, which is not quite what this form is intended for). An attacker might be able to get away with cookies, but there's probably sides to this I don't know about.

And of course, there's also the cost/benefit aspect of this.

Comment: i don't see any risk from the details. If someone wants to self-own, [f12] is a much simpler way of doing it than injecting code into self-filled-out form fields.

Comment: If your users can't access any data but their own seems like you can allow inline styles.

Comment: @dandavis The data from the form is passed as query string parameters to the preview page. So I can add script tags etc in the URL, and send the URL to others. That won't do any harm though, since I HTML encode all the data before adding it to the HTML. So I don't think there's a way to get any CSS injected here, but never say never, I guess.